# pass variables from php file to html file

Tags: php, html, pass-data

so i have code php like this:

```
$fname="dor";
$fname=$_POST["fname"];
```

and i want to pass the $fname from the php file to an html file

in my html file i want to print on the screen "dor"

how to do it?

but when i run it i get this error:

```
Undefined index: fname
```

what should i do?
tnx for helpers :)

Comment: From a PHP to a HTML file? This is not possible. Unless you are talking the other way around.

Comment: `$fname=$_POST["fname"];` are you getting fname from a `form`

Answer (score 0):

you can include a PHP file -

index.php:

```
<?Php
 include 'variable.php';
 if(!$fname) // if $fname does not exists then create it with no value
   $fname = null;
?>
<form action="myphpfile.php" method="POST">
    Name: <input type="text" name="fname" value="$fname" />
    <input type="submit" />
```

variable.php:

```
<?Php
  $fname = 'Dor';
?>
```

myphpfile.php:

```
<?Php
   print $_POST['fname']; // will print the value of fname after submitting the form
?>
```

Comment: You need `<?php echo $fname ?>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use this.

```
Name: <input type="text" name="fname" value=<?= $fname ?> />
```

Comment: i got wrong with my question can you look again? – Dor Cohen just now edit

Comment: What is the output of var_dump($_POST) ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to pass data from PHP to a HTML file.

If your question is to display a php variable value with html markup, you should create a php file and do something like this:

```
<?php
$fname = "test";
?>
<div><?php echo $fname; ?></div>
```